# How to make a program restart itself after a computer has been rebooted or turned off and on

Tags: c++

I'm doing a program for fun and trying out new things in c++ and I am wondering is there any way to restart an exe file after the computer it was running on was rebooted or turned off and on.

Comment: That's a system-specific config thing. Google for whatever OS you use.

Comment: Not in C++ there isn't (or any other language I can think of).

Comment: Look up how to automatically launch a program upon startup for whatever OS you're using.

Comment: Your OS has specific support for this.  Google what you want to know with "c++ windows restart manager".